# iMac keeps crashing using Photoshop

Tags: imac, crash, kernel-panic, adobe-photoshop

My 2018 iMac keeps crashing sometimes 2-3 times a day while I am working with Photoshop. I have 64GB RAM but still have that issue. Hopefully some can help me read the crash report. I work primarily on Photoshop and is really distracting and frustrating to have that issue.

```
panic(cpu 1 caller 0xffffff801d96ea25): userspace watchdog timeout: no successful checkins from com.apple.logd in 120 seconds
service returned not alive with context : unresponsive dispatch queue(s): com.apple.firehose.io-wl 
service: com.apple.logd, total successful checkins since load (4840 seconds ago): 473, last successful checkin: 120 seconds ago
service: com.apple.WindowServer, total successful checkins since load (4750 seconds ago): 470, last successful checkin: 50 seconds ago

Backtrace (CPU 1), Frame : Return Address
0xffffffa1bd6db670 : 0xffffff801a6b9aed 
0xffffffa1bd6db6c0 : 0xffffff801a7fc6e3 
0xffffffa1bd6db700 : 0xffffff801a7ecd1a 
0xffffffa1bd6db750 : 0xffffff801a65ea2f 
0xffffffa1bd6db770 : 0xffffff801a6b938d 
0xffffffa1bd6db890 : 0xffffff801a6b9678 
0xffffffa1bd6db900 : 0xffffff801aebe434 
0xffffffa1bd6db970 : 0xffffff801d96ea25 
0xffffffa1bd6db980 : 0xffffff801d96e678 
0xffffffa1bd6db9a0 : 0xffffff801ae4569e 
0xffffffa1bd6db9f0 : 0xffffff801d96dab4 
0xffffffa1bd6dbb20 : 0xffffff801ae4f86b 
0xffffffa1bd6dbc80 : 0xffffff801a7a7d81 
0xffffffa1bd6dbd90 : 0xffffff801a6bf0e7 
0xffffffa1bd6dbe00 : 0xffffff801a695905 
0xffffffa1bd6dbe60 : 0xffffff801a6ad012 
0xffffffa1bd6dbef0 : 0xffffff801a7d0ec3 
0xffffffa1bd6dbfa0 : 0xffffff801a65f216 
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.apple.driver.watchdog(1.0)[7AE04EA4-D026-39A0-B2D5-5C9E4EE72967]@0xffffff801d96d000->0xffffff801d96efff

Process name corresponding to current thread: watchdogd

Mac OS version:
20C69

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 20.2.0: Wed Dec  2 20:39:59 PST 2020; root:xnu-7195.60.75~1/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 82E2050C-5936-3D24-AD3B-EC4EC5C09E11
KernelCache slide: 0x000000001a400000
KernelCache base:  0xffffff801a600000
Kernel slide:      0x000000001a410000
Kernel text base:  0xffffff801a610000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff801a500000
System model name: iMac18,3 (Mac-BE088AF8C5EB4FA2)
System shutdown begun: NO
Panic diags file available: YES (0x0)
Hibernation exit count: 0

System uptime in nanoseconds: 4870160650120
Last Sleep:           absolute           base_tsc          base_nano
  Uptime  : 0x0000046dec3211d2
  Sleep   : 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000
  Wake    : 0x0000000000000000 0x00000010e83b3edc 0x0000000000000000
last started kext at 219169840317: @filesystems.msdosfs 1.10 (addr 0xffffff7fbb7db000, size 57344)
loaded kexts:
@filesystems.msdosfs    1.10
@filesystems.exfat  1.4
>!ATopCaseHIDEventDriver    4020.6
>AudioAUUC  1.70
>!APlatformEnabler  2.7.0d0
>AGPM   119
>X86PlatformShim    1.0.0
@fsplaceholder  1.13.2
>!AUpstreamUserClient   3.6.8
@filesystems.autofs 3.0
@kext.AMDFramebuffer    4.0.2
@fileutil   20.036.15
@kext.AMDRadeonX4000    4.0.2
>!AHDAHardwareConfigDriver  283.15
@kext.AMDRadeonServiceManager   4.0.2
>!AHDA  283.15
>!AGraphicsDevicePolicy 6.2.2
@AGDCPluginDisplayMetrics   6.2.2
>pmtelemetry    1
>LuaHardwareAccess  1.0.16
|IOUserEthernet 1.0.1
>usb.!UUserHCI  1
|IO!BSerialManager  8.0.2f9
@Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X    7.0.0
@kext.AMD9500!C 4.0.2
>!AHV   1
>!AFIVRDriver   4.1.0
>AGDCBacklightControl   6.2.2
>!ADiskImages2  1
>!AThunderboltIP    4.0.3
>!A!IKBLGraphics    16.0.1
>!ABacklight    180.3
>!A!ISlowAdaptiveClocking   4.0.0
>!A!IPCHPMC 2.0.1
>ACPI_SMC_PlatformPlugin    1.0.0
>!AMCCSControl  1.14
>!ASMCLMU   212
|Broadcom!B20703USBTransport    8.0.2f9
>!AGFXHDA   100.1.431
>eficheck   1
>!A!IKBLGraphicsFramebuffer 16.0.1
>Core!SFsck 554
|IO!BUSBDFU 8.0.2f9
|SCSITaskUserClient 436.40.6
>!AFileSystemDriver 3.0.1
@filesystems.tmpfs  1
@filesystems.hfs.kext   556.60.1
@BootCache  40
@!AFSCompression.!AFSCompressionTypeZlib    1.0.0
@!AFSCompression.!AFSCompressionTypeDataless    1.0.0d1
@filesystems.apfs   1677.60.23
>!ASDXC 1.9.0
|!ABCM5701Ethernet  11.0.0
>AirPort.BrcmNIC    1400.1.1
>!AAHCIPort 346
@private.KextAudit  1.0
>!AACPIButtons  6.1
>!ARTC  2.0
>!ASMBIOS   2.1
>!AACPIEC   6.1
>!AAPIC 1.7
@!ASystemPolicy 2.0.0
@nke.applicationfirewall    310
|IOKitRegistryCompatibility 1
|EndpointSecurity   1
>!AHIDKeyboard  222
>!AMultitouchDriver 4400.28
>!AInputDeviceSupport   4400.35
>!AHS!BDriver   4020.6
>IO!BHIDDriver  8.0.2f9
>!UAudio    401.4
@kext.triggers  1.0
@kext.AMDRadeonX4200HWLibs  1.0
@kext.AMDRadeonX4000HWServices  4.0.2
>DspFuncLib 283.15
@kext.OSvKernDSPLib 529
>!AGraphicsControl  6.2.2
|IOSerial!F 11
|IOAVB!F    900.12
@plugin.IOgPTPPlugin    900.11
|IOEthernetAVB!C    1.1.0
@kext.AMDSupport    4.0.2
>!AThunderboltEDMSink   5.0.3
>!AThunderboltDPOutAdapter  8.1.4
>!ABacklightExpert  1.1.0
@!AGPUWrangler  6.2.2
|IOSlowAdaptiveClocking!F   1.0.0
>!ASMBusPCI 1.0.14d1
>IOPlatformPluginLegacy 1.0.0
>X86PlatformPlugin  1.0.0
>IOPlatformPlugin!F 6.0.0d8
>!ASMBus!C  1.0.18d1
|Broadcom!BHost!CUSBTransport   8.0.2f9
|IO!BHost!CUSBTransport 8.0.2f9
|IO!BHost!CTransport    8.0.2f9
>!AHDA!C    283.15
|IOHDA!F    283.15
|IONDRVSupport  585
|IOAudio!F  300.6.1
@vecLib.kext    1.2.0
|IOAccelerator!F2   439.52
@!AGraphicsDeviceControl    6.2.2
|IOGraphics!F   585
>Core!S 554
>usb.IOUSBHostHIDDevice 1.2
>usb.!UHub  1.2
>usb.cdc    5.0.0
>usb.networking 5.0.0
>usb.!UHostCompositeDevice  1.2
>!AThunderboltDPInAdapter   8.1.4
>!AThunderboltDPAdapter!F   8.1.4
>!AThunderboltPCIUpAdapter  4.1.1
>!AThunderboltPCIDownAdapter    4.1.1
>!AHPM  3.4.4
>!A!ILpssI2C!C  3.0.60
>!A!ILpssDmac   3.0.60
>!ABSDKextStarter   3
|IOSurface  289.3
@filesystems.hfs.encodings.kext 1
>!AXsanScheme   3
|IOAHCIBlock!S  332
>!AThunderboltNHI   7.2.8
|IOThunderbolt!F    9.3.2
|IO80211!F  1200.12.2b1
|IOSkywalk!F    1
>mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
>corecapture    1.0.4
|IONVMe!F   2.1.0
>!A!ILpssI2C    3.0.60
>!A!ILpssGspi   3.0.60
|IOAHCI!F   294
>usb.!UXHCIPCI  1.2
>usb.!UXHCI 1.2
>usb.!UHostPacketFilter 1.0
|IOUSB!F    900.4.2
>!AEFINVRAM 2.1
>!AEFIRuntime   2.1
|IOSMBus!F  1.1
|IOHID!F    2.0.0
$!AImage4   3.0.0
|IOTimeSync!F   900.11
|IONetworking!F 3.4
>DiskImages 493.0.0
|IO!B!F 8.0.2f9
|IOReport!F 47
|IO!BPacketLogger   8.0.2f9
$quarantine 4
$sandbox    300.0
@kext.!AMatch   1.0.0d1
|CoreAnalytics!F    1
>!ASSE  1.0
>!AKeyStore 2
>!UTDM  511.60.2
|IOUSBMass!SDriver  184.40.6
|IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice  436.40.6
|IO!S!F 2.1
|IOSCSIArchitectureModel!F  436.40.6
>!AMobileFileIntegrity  1.0.5
@kext.CoreTrust 1
>!AFDEKeyStore  28.30
>!AEffaceable!S 1.0
>!ACredentialManager    1.0
>KernelRelayHost    1
|IOUSBHost!F    1.2
>!UHostMergeProperties  1.2
>usb.!UCommon   1.0
>!ABusPower!C   1.0
>!ASEPManager   1.0.1
>IOSlaveProcessor   1
>!AACPIPlatform 6.1
>!ASMC  3.1.9
|IOPCI!F    2.9
|IOACPI!F   1.4
>watchdog   1
@kec.pthread    1
@kec.corecrypto 11.1
@kec.Libm   1
```

Comment: What version Photoshop? (On phone so can’t read or reformat the report )

Comment: I have 20.0.6 and 22.5.1. Doesn't matter which one I use. The Comp is crashing.

Comment: What action are you performing when it crashes? I've known Photoshop to hang the machine back to login screen - which turned out the GPU acceleration needed winding back a step or two, as it wasn't playing nicely with another app that was also using OpenGL. [It does not share OpenGL well at all] Yours looks like it might be trying to write to FAT… but hard to tell. `watchdogd` is giving up after something "stopped working fast enough" which I'm not qualified to test further, sorry.

Comment: It's random actions, I didn't notice any pattern. It could be anything, trying to create a new layer, selecting a layer, or just scrolling through the menu. I will try to install a fresh copy of Catalina over the weekend, because everything started after updating the OS to Big Sur. Meanwhile, I'll check which of my other apps use OpenGL and see if that's the problem.